# Display extracted feature vector from trained layer of the model as an image

Tags: python, numpy, keras, feature-extraction, keras-layer

I am using  Transfer learning for recognizing objects. I used trained VGG16 model as the base model and added my classifier on top of it using Keras. I then trained the model on my data, the model works well. I want to see the feature generated by the intermediate layers of the model for the given data. I used the following code for this purpose:

```
def ModeloutputAtthisLayer(model, layernme, imgnme, width, height):

    layer_name = layernme
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                     outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
    img = image.load_img(imgnme, target_size=(width, height))
    imageArray = image.img_to_array(img)
    image_batch = np.expand_dims(imageArray, axis=0)
    processed_image = preprocess_input(image_batch.copy())
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(processed_image)
    print("outshape of ", layernme, "is ", intermediate_output.shape)
```

In the code, I used `np.expand_dims` to add one extra dimension for the batch as the input matrix to the network should be  of the form `(batchsize, height, width, channels)`. This code works fine. The shape of the feature vector is `1, 224, 224, 64`.

Now I wish to display this as image, for this I understand there is an additional dimension added as batch so I should remove it. Following this I used the following lines of the code:

```
imge = np.squeeze(intermediate_output, axis=0)
plt.imshow(imge)
```

However it throws an error:

> "Invalid dimensions for image data"

I wonder how can I display the extracted feature vector as an image. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature shape is `(1,224,224,64)`, you cannot directly plot a `64` channel image. What you can do is plot the individual channels independently like following

```
imge = np.squeeze(intermediate_output, axis=0)
filters = imge.shape[2]
plt.figure(1, figsize=(32, 32))   # plot image of size (32x32)
n_columns = 8
n_rows = math.ceil(filters / n_columns) + 1
for i in range(filters):
    plt.subplot(n_rows, n_columns, i+1)
    plt.title('Filter ' + str(i))
    plt.imshow(imge[:,:,i], interpolation="nearest", cmap="gray")
```

This will plot `64` images in `8` rows and `8` columns.

Comment: Thanks ,does this means that a simple RGB image having three channel should also be drawn separately,

Comment: They can be drawn separately but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: my point is that if we can draw all three i.e. RGB channels as one image why can't we do the same for more than three channels, in this case, 64 channels.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to go consists in combining the 64 channels into a single-channel image through a weighted sum like this:

```
weighted_imge = np.sum(imge*weights, axis=-1)
```

where `weights` is an array with 64 weighting coefficients.

If you wish to give all the channels the same weight you could simply compute the average:

```
weighted_imge = np.mean(imge, axis=-1)
```

#### Demo

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intermediate_output = np.random.randint(size=(1, 224, 224, 64), 
                                        low=0, high=2**8, dtype=np.uint8)
imge = np.squeeze(intermediate_output, axis=0)
weights = np.random.random(size=(imge.shape[-1],))

weighted_imge = np.sum(imge*weights, axis=-1)

plt.imshow(weighted_imge)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: weighted_imge]

```
In [33]: intermediate_output.shape
Out[33]: (1, 224, 224, 64)

In [34]: imge.shape
Out[34]: (224, 224, 64)

In [35]: weights.shape
Out[35]: (64,)

In [36]: weighted_imge.shape
Out[36]: (224, 224)
```